# View raw packet-level data using python sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, tcp, packet

Is it possible to view the raw socket data that is sent to a server via the `sockets` module? For example, the following will print the client request in bytes:

```
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('', 1))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(200)
            print ("INCOMING BYTES:", data) # how to view the actual sent TCP packet data ?
            if not data: break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Comment: Yes. Use the `socket.SOCK_RAW` instead of `socket.SOCK_STREAM`. It might also make sense to bind to a non-registered port instead of 1 on line 3. Program Creek has some [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/7887/socket.SOCK_RAW) of socket.SOCK_RAW